# Why I'm getting this error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this code to insert data to MySQL. The error occur when I try to call the function register_emp(). Can you please tell me what to do in order to fix this kind of error. Thank you.

```
if($user->register_emp($last,$first,$middle,$middle,
                        $address,$contact,$email,$birth,$gender,
                        $status,$citizen,$position,$dependent))
{
    try
    {

        $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) as LastID from employeeprofile");
        $stmt->execute(array());
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
        $owner=$userRow['LastID'];

        if($user->register_contrib($owner,$sss,$tin,$pagibig,$phil)){
            $user->redirect('admin1.php');
        }
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
```

This is the register_emp function that I'm trying to call.

```
public function register_emp($last,$first,$middle,$address,
                            $zip,$contact,$email,$birth,
                            $gender,$status,$citizen,$position,$dependent)
{
    try
    {


        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `proll`.`employeeprofile` 
        (`Lastname`, `Firstname`, `Middlename`, `Address`, `ZIP`, `Contact`, `Email`, `Birthdate`, `Gender`, `Status`, `Citizenship`, `Position`, `Dependent`) VALUES 
        (:last,:first,:middle,:address,:zip,:contact,:email,:birth,:gender,:status,:citizenship,:position,:dependent)");


        $stmt->bindparam(":last", $last);
        $stmt->bindparam(":first", $first);
        $stmt->bindparam(":middle", $middle);
        $stmt->bindparam(":address", $address);
        $stmt->bindparam(":zip", $zip);
        $stmt->bindparam(":contact", $contact);
        $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindparam(":birth", $birth);
        $stmt->bindparam(":gender", $gender);
        $stmt->bindparam(":status", $status);       
        $stmt->bindparam(":citizen", $citizen); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":position", $position);
        $stmt->bindparam(":dependent", $dependent);


        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be coming from runQuery. Check register_emp and register_contrib and look for the line number/file in the error.

Comment: You had better show us what `runQuery()` does. If it runs a `->query()` that would explain some issues

Comment: I would guess the array parameter being passed in a `->execute()` that does not need any parameters may be the issue. Try `$stmt->execute()` and see if the error dissappears

Comment: I seem to remember a question that was using a method called `runQuery()` from yesterday. Cannot remember if it was doing a prepare or a query. If it is doing a prepare it is the worst named method in history

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. But the error occurs when I try to call the register_emp "if($user->register_emp($last,$first,$middle,$middle,$address,$contact,$email,$birth,$gender,$status,$citizen,$position,$dependent)){". This is the exact line where the error occurs

Comment: A bit of sensible code indentation show one issue _to many `}` in first code_

Comment: The error is not about braces. Its all about the error on register_emp function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with citizen/citizenship. You're using different words for the prepare statement and binding:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `proll`.`employeeprofile` 
    (`Lastname`, `Firstname`, `Middlename`, `Address`, `ZIP`, `Contact`, `Email`, `Birthdate`, `Gender`, `Status`, `Citizenship`, `Position`, `Dependent`) VALUES 
    (:last,:first,:middle,:address,:zip,:contact,:email,:birth,:gender,:status,:citizenship,:position,:dependent)");

....

    $stmt->bindparam(":citizen", $citizen);
```

Change them to be the same word, and you'll be good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. God bless